# Issues printing ZPL via powershell

Tags: powershell, zebra-printers, zpl

## Issue printing ZPL using powershell

I'm struggling to print a label based on ZPL commands via Powershell.
Im using this line to print the labels:

```
Get-Content ($folder + $labelname + '.txt')|Out-Printer -Name "Generic / Text Only"
```

When I run this an empty label comes out. I did some tests to narrow it down.

- When I open the .txt file with notepad and print it manually, the label comes out fine

So it seems there aren't any issues with the syntax of the zpl commands.

The simple conclusion I made at that point, was that my powershell line isn't working.

To check this I used a simple zpl expample and stored it in a .txt file. When I used the same powershell line to print this label, it worked.

From this I concluded that there is something in the ZPL commands which causes problems for powershell. So I compared the ZPL commands and noticed that the non-working ZPL file uses ~DGR:TFORMer.GRF (see full content below) to generate an image.

**Content of nonworkinglabel.txt:**

```
^FXParcel_Std^FS
^MMT
^JMA
~DGR:TFORMer.GRF,121160,104,
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzlG03SFEg0jKF8jM0....FpM02zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzznR0
^XA
^PW832
^LH0,0
^LS0
^LT0
^LL1165
^FO0,0
^XGTFORMer.GRF,1,1^FS
^XZ
^XA
^IDTFORMer.GRF^FS
^XZ
```

*I left out some of the line underneath ~DGR:TFORMer.GRF,121160,104, because the page kept crasing*

What do I have to change to my powershell script to make this work? Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Can you show us what `$folder + $labelname + '.txt'` results in? Is that a full, absolute path? What if you append switch `-Raw` to the Get-Content call, so it will send one multiline string through the pipeline?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The path is indeed a full path. I've tried to put -raw in but it also does not work.

Comment: Update, I've found a workaround by using the following powershell line.
```Start-Process -filepath ($folders.ToLabel + $label.Barcode +'.txt') -Verb print```
 It works but now notepad appears for a few seconds.  Is there a way to let this run on the background? ```-Windowstyle Hidden``` doesn't work.